# Html, мобильный вид страницы

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Почему при комбинации клавиш Ctrl+Shift+m браузер отображает нормальный вид страны для мобильных версий, а на телефоне всё очень плохо, т.е. размеры не меняются и всё так же, как на компьютере/ноутбуке?

Comment: @Даниил, а у меня это уже было, всё равно страница покрученная на телефоне) Кэш?

Comment: Ну т.е. не такая, какой должна быть. Не поверите, кэш уже чистила)

Comment: Госпадя, перезагружала всё что можно и не можно) И даже здесь цифру меняла: `<link href="post.css?3" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`. Вот ссылка: http://kurusa.zhecky.net/lesson_16/html_log_in.php

Comment: Ну и ладно :ссс

Comment: Но... оно и так уже у меня есть

Comment: Ой, простите, не туда смотрела ><

Comment: Совсем другое дело. Спасибо с: Это просто снова моя невнимательность. Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет:

Добавить между `<head> </head>` строку:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```